# Как распарсить в с# SOAP ответ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, soap

Есть вот такой SOAP ответ

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?><GetInformReply><Inform_ID>14</Inform_ID><ASOUPReply><![CDATA[<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:getReference14ASUResponse xmlns:ns2="http://service.siw.pktbcki.rzd/"><return><reference14ASU><row><NOM_VAG>66236936</NOM_VAG><NOM_NAK>ЭЫ512933</NOM_NAK><NOM_NAK_1></NOM_NAK_1><NOM_NAK_2></NOM_NAK_2><NOM_NAK_3></NOM_NAK_3><NOM_NAK_4></NOM_NAK_4><NOM_NAK_5></NOM_NAK_5><NOM_NAK_6></NOM_NAK_6><NOM_NAK_7></NOM_NAK_7><NOM_NAK_8></NOM_NAK_8><NOM_NAK_9></NOM_NAK_9><NOM_NAK_10></NOM_NAK_10><NOM_NAK_11></NOM_NAK_11><NOM_NAK_12></NOM_NAK_12><NOM_NAK_13></NOM_NAK_13><ROD_VAG_UCH>60</ROD_VAG_UCH><NAIM_ROD_VAG>Полувагоны</NAIM_ROD_VAG><KOD_STR>643</KOD_STR><KOD_SOB>20</KOD_SOB><NAIM_KOD_SOB>PЖД</NAIM_KOD_SOB><DATE_NACH>2015-03-07T05:04:00.000</DATE_NACH><STR_NACH>643</STR_NACH><NAIM_STR_NACH>Российская Федерация</NAIM_STR_NACH><DOR_NACH>96</DOR_NACH><NAIM_DOR_NACH>ДAЛЬHEBOCTOЧHAЯ</NAIM_DOR_NACH><STAN_NACH>967808</STAN_NACH><NAIM_STAN_NACH>ВАНИНО (ЭКСП.)</NAIM_STAN_NACH><DATE_KON xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/><STR_NAZN>643</STR_NAZN><NAIM_STR_NAZN>Российская Федерация</NAIM_STR_NAZN><STAN_NAZN>886808</STAN_NAZN><NAIM_STAN_NAZN>ТЕЯ</NAIM_STAN_NAZN><DOR_NAZN>88</DOR_NAZN><NAIM_DOR_NAZN>KPACHOЯPCKAЯ</NAIM_DOR_NAZN><GRUZPOL>7035</GRUZPOL><GRUZPOL_OKPO>23341100</GRUZPOL_OKPO><NAIM_GRUZPOL_OKPO>ООО "ТЕЙСКИЙ РУДНИК"</NAIM_GRUZPOL_OKPO><GRUZOTPR>2920</GRUZOTPR><GRUZOTPR_OKPO>0</GRUZOTPR_OKPO><NAIM_GRUZOTPR_OKPO></NAIM_GRUZOTPR_OKPO><KOD_GRZ_TGNL>161043</KOD_GRZ_TGNL><NAIM_KOD_GRZ>Концентрат угольный</NAIM_KOD_GRZ><KOD_GRZ_GNG>992200000000</KOD_GRZ_GNG><PROB_GRJ>75225</PROB_GRJ><PROB_POR>64651</PROB_POR><OS_OTM1>0</OS_OTM1><OS_OTM2>0</OS_OTM2><OS_OTM3>0</OS_OTM3><VES_GRZ>0</VES_GRZ><DATE_OP>2017-08-10T23:00:00.000</DATE_OP><DOR_RASCH>94</DOR_RASCH><NAIM_DOR_RASCH>ЗAБAЙKAЛЬCKAЯ</NAIM_DOR_RASCH><STAN_OP>942105</STAN_OP><NAIM_STAN_OP>КАДАЛА</NAIM_STAN_OP><KOP_VMD>80</KOP_VMD><NAIM_KOP_VMD>Подача вагона на подъездной путь</NAIM_KOP_VMD><KOP_PMD>0</KOP_PMD><NAIM_KOP_PMD></NAIM_KOP_PMD><PPV_MEST>0</PPV_MEST><PPV_TRANZ>1</PPV_TRANZ><PPV_POR>1</PPV_POR><PPV_GRUJ>0</PPV_GRUJ><PPV_NRP>1</PPV_NRP><PPV_RP>0</PPV_RP><VNRP_NEISP>1</VNRP_NEISP><VNRP_SPEC_TEX>0</VNRP_SPEC_TEX><DOR_SDACH>96</DOR_SDACH><NAIM_DOR_SDACH>ДAЛЬHEBOCTOЧHAЯ</NAIM_DOR_SDACH><INDEX_POEZD>000000000000000</INDEX_POEZD><NAIM_INDEX_POEZD></NAIM_INDEX_POEZD><NOM_POEZD>0</NOM_POEZD><NPP_VAG>0</NPP_VAG><KOL_GRJ_STK>0</KOL_GRJ_STK><KOL_POR_STK>0</KOL_POR_STK><KOL_GRJ_KTK>0</KOL_GRJ_KTK><KOL_POR_KTK>0</KOL_POR_KTK><KOD_GRZ_UCH>161043</KOD_GRZ_UCH><NAIM_KOD_GRZ_UCH>Концентрат угольный</NAIM_KOD_GRZ_UCH><DATE_NAZN xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/><KOL_GRUJ>0</KOL_GRUJ><KOL_POR>0</KOL_POR><KOL_NRP>0</KOL_NRP><KOL_VAG>0</KOL_VAG><USL_DL_POEZD>0</USL_DL_POEZD><VES_BR>0</VES_BR><PR_STR>1</PR_STR><NOM_PARK>3</NOM_PARK><NAIM_NOM_PARK>Грузовой двор</NAIM_NOM_PARK><NOM_PUT>3</NOM_PUT><NAIM_NOM_PUT>3г</NAIM_NOM_PUT><KOL_ZPU>0</KOL_ZPU><KOL_GRJ_KONT>0</KOL_GRJ_KONT><KOL_POR_KONT>0</KOL_POR_KONT><NOM_KON1>           </NOM_KON1><NOM_KON2>           </NOM_KON2><NOM_KON3>           </NOM_KON3><NOM_KON4>           </NOM_KON4><NOM_KON5>           </NOM_KON5><NOM_KON6>           </NOM_KON6><NOM_KON7>           </NOM_KON7><NOM_KON8>           </NOM_KON8><NOM_KON9>           </NOM_KON9><NOM_KON10>           </NOM_KON10><NOM_KON11>           </NOM_KON11><NOM_KON12>           </NOM_KON12><NOM_KON13>           </NOM_KON13><NOM_KON14>           </NOM_KON14><DATE_DOSTAV>2015-03-22T23:59:59.000</DATE_DOSTAV><RASST_OB>      5545</RASST_OB><RASST_STAN_OP>      3017</RASST_STAN_OP><RASST_STAN_NAZN>      2528</RASST_STAN_NAZN><UNO>            </UNO><MNAIM_KOP_VMD>ПBПП</MNAIM_KOP_VMD><PROST_DN>1270</PROST_DN><PROST_MIN>49</PROST_MIN><ID_OTPRK>2096ЭЫ512933</ID_OTPRK><PROST_CH>11</PROST_CH></row></reference14ASU><amount>1</amount><amountRF>1</amountRF><amountNotRF>0</amountNotRF><codeTypeObject>1</codeTypeObject><returnCode>0</returnCode><errorCode>0</errorCode><errorMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/><title>Справка о дислокации вагонов по списку</title></return></ns2:getReference14ASUResponse></S:Body></S:Envelope>]]></ASOUPReply></GetInformReply>
```

Пытаюсь распарсить его...

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(soapResult);
XNamespace a = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
XNamespace b = "SysEtranInt";

foreach (XElement VElement in xdoc.Element(a + "Envelope").Element(a + "Body").Elements(b + "GetBlockResponse"))
{
    XAttribute nameAttribute = VElement.Attribute("value");
    XElement priceElement = VElement.Element("Text");
```

Дальше при попытке распарсить вложенный ответ он спотыкается на

```
<![CDATA[<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

Как обойти `![CDATA[<?xml` и все правильно распарсить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это двухэтапный процесс, потому что настоящий ответ SOAP упакован внутри раздела CDATA.

Я сохранил ваш XML в файле для простоты.

c# ниже показывает как к этому SOAP Envelope добраться. После этого переменную **realdoc** можно будет обработать с помощью LINQ to XML.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string inputXMLFile = @"e:\Temp\RomanEgorov.xml";
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(inputXMLFile);
    
    XDocument realDoc = XDocument.Parse(xdoc.Descendants("ASOUPReply").FirstOrDefault().Value);
    Console.Write(realDoc);

    foreach(XElement elem in realDoc.Descendants("row").Elements())
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(elem.Value))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", elem.Name, elem.Value.Trim());
        }
    }
}
```

**Результат**

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
    <ns2:getReference14ASUResponse xmlns:ns2="http://service.siw.pktbcki.rzd/">
      <return>
        <reference14ASU>
          <row>
            <NOM_VAG>66236936</NOM_VAG>
            <NOM_NAK>ЭЫ512933</NOM_NAK>
            <NOM_NAK_1></NOM_NAK_1>
            <NOM_NAK_2></NOM_NAK_2>
            <NOM_NAK_3></NOM_NAK_3>
            <NOM_NAK_4></NOM_NAK_4>
            <NOM_NAK_5></NOM_NAK_5>
            <NOM_NAK_6></NOM_NAK_6>
            <NOM_NAK_7></NOM_NAK_7>
            <NOM_NAK_8></NOM_NAK_8>
            <NOM_NAK_9></NOM_NAK_9>
            <NOM_NAK_10></NOM_NAK_10>
            <NOM_NAK_11></NOM_NAK_11>
            <NOM_NAK_12></NOM_NAK_12>
            <NOM_NAK_13></NOM_NAK_13>
            <ROD_VAG_UCH>60</ROD_VAG_UCH>
            <NAIM_ROD_VAG>Полувагоны</NAIM_ROD_VAG>
            <KOD_STR>643</KOD_STR>
            <KOD_SOB>20</KOD_SOB>
            <NAIM_KOD_SOB>PЖД</NAIM_KOD_SOB>
            <DATE_NACH>2015-03-07T05:04:00.000</DATE_NACH>
            <STR_NACH>643</STR_NACH>
            <NAIM_STR_NACH>Российская Федерация</NAIM_STR_NACH>
            <DOR_NACH>96</DOR_NACH>
            <NAIM_DOR_NACH>ДAЛЬHEBOCTOЧHAЯ</NAIM_DOR_NACH>
            <STAN_NACH>967808</STAN_NACH>
            <NAIM_STAN_NACH>ВАНИНО (ЭКСП.)</NAIM_STAN_NACH>
            <DATE_KON xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
            <STR_NAZN>643</STR_NAZN>
            <NAIM_STR_NAZN>Российская Федерация</NAIM_STR_NAZN>
            <STAN_NAZN>886808</STAN_NAZN>
            <NAIM_STAN_NAZN>ТЕЯ</NAIM_STAN_NAZN>
            <DOR_NAZN>88</DOR_NAZN>
            <NAIM_DOR_NAZN>KPACHOЯPCKAЯ</NAIM_DOR_NAZN>
            <GRUZPOL>7035</GRUZPOL>
            <GRUZPOL_OKPO>23341100</GRUZPOL_OKPO>
            <NAIM_GRUZPOL_OKPO>ООО "ТЕЙСКИЙ РУДНИК"</NAIM_GRUZPOL_OKPO>
            <GRUZOTPR>2920</GRUZOTPR>
            <GRUZOTPR_OKPO>0</GRUZOTPR_OKPO>
            <NAIM_GRUZOTPR_OKPO></NAIM_GRUZOTPR_OKPO>
            <KOD_GRZ_TGNL>161043</KOD_GRZ_TGNL>
            <NAIM_KOD_GRZ>Концентрат угольный</NAIM_KOD_GRZ>
            <KOD_GRZ_GNG>992200000000</KOD_GRZ_GNG>
            <PROB_GRJ>75225</PROB_GRJ>
            <PROB_POR>64651</PROB_POR>
            <OS_OTM1>0</OS_OTM1>
            <OS_OTM2>0</OS_OTM2>
            <OS_OTM3>0</OS_OTM3>
            <VES_GRZ>0</VES_GRZ>
            <DATE_OP>2017-08-10T23:00:00.000</DATE_OP>
            <DOR_RASCH>94</DOR_RASCH>
            <NAIM_DOR_RASCH>ЗAБAЙKAЛЬCKAЯ</NAIM_DOR_RASCH>
            <STAN_OP>942105</STAN_OP>
            <NAIM_STAN_OP>КАДАЛА</NAIM_STAN_OP>
            <KOP_VMD>80</KOP_VMD>
            <NAIM_KOP_VMD>Подача вагона на подъездной путь</NAIM_KOP_VMD>
            <KOP_PMD>0</KOP_PMD>
            <NAIM_KOP_PMD></NAIM_KOP_PMD>
            <PPV_MEST>0</PPV_MEST>
            <PPV_TRANZ>1</PPV_TRANZ>
            <PPV_POR>1</PPV_POR>
            <PPV_GRUJ>0</PPV_GRUJ>
            <PPV_NRP>1</PPV_NRP>
            <PPV_RP>0</PPV_RP>
            <VNRP_NEISP>1</VNRP_NEISP>
            <VNRP_SPEC_TEX>0</VNRP_SPEC_TEX>
            <DOR_SDACH>96</DOR_SDACH>
            <NAIM_DOR_SDACH>ДAЛЬHEBOCTOЧHAЯ</NAIM_DOR_SDACH>
            <INDEX_POEZD>000000000000000</INDEX_POEZD>
            <NAIM_INDEX_POEZD></NAIM_INDEX_POEZD>
            <NOM_POEZD>0</NOM_POEZD>
            <NPP_VAG>0</NPP_VAG>
            <KOL_GRJ_STK>0</KOL_GRJ_STK>
            <KOL_POR_STK>0</KOL_POR_STK>
            <KOL_GRJ_KTK>0</KOL_GRJ_KTK>
            <KOL_POR_KTK>0</KOL_POR_KTK>
            <KOD_GRZ_UCH>161043</KOD_GRZ_UCH>
            <NAIM_KOD_GRZ_UCH>Концентрат угольный</NAIM_KOD_GRZ_UCH>
            <DATE_NAZN xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
            <KOL_GRUJ>0</KOL_GRUJ>
            <KOL_POR>0</KOL_POR>
            <KOL_NRP>0</KOL_NRP>
            <KOL_VAG>0</KOL_VAG>
            <USL_DL_POEZD>0</USL_DL_POEZD>
            <VES_BR>0</VES_BR>
            <PR_STR>1</PR_STR>
            <NOM_PARK>3</NOM_PARK>
            <NAIM_NOM_PARK>Грузовой двор</NAIM_NOM_PARK>
            <NOM_PUT>3</NOM_PUT>
            <NAIM_NOM_PUT>3г</NAIM_NOM_PUT>
            <KOL_ZPU>0</KOL_ZPU>
            <KOL_GRJ_KONT>0</KOL_GRJ_KONT>
            <KOL_POR_KONT>0</KOL_POR_KONT>
            <NOM_KON1></NOM_KON1>
            <NOM_KON2></NOM_KON2>
            <NOM_KON3></NOM_KON3>
            <NOM_KON4></NOM_KON4>
            <NOM_KON5></NOM_KON5>
            <NOM_KON6></NOM_KON6>
            <NOM_KON7></NOM_KON7>
            <NOM_KON8></NOM_KON8>
            <NOM_KON9></NOM_KON9>
            <NOM_KON10></NOM_KON10>
            <NOM_KON11></NOM_KON11>
            <NOM_KON12></NOM_KON12>
            <NOM_KON13></NOM_KON13>
            <NOM_KON14></NOM_KON14>
            <DATE_DOSTAV>2015-03-22T23:59:59.000</DATE_DOSTAV>
            <RASST_OB>      5545</RASST_OB>
            <RASST_STAN_OP>      3017</RASST_STAN_OP>
            <RASST_STAN_NAZN>      2528</RASST_STAN_NAZN>
            <UNO></UNO>
            <MNAIM_KOP_VMD>ПBПП</MNAIM_KOP_VMD>
            <PROST_DN>1270</PROST_DN>
            <PROST_MIN>49</PROST_MIN>
            <ID_OTPRK>2096ЭЫ512933</ID_OTPRK>
            <PROST_CH>11</PROST_CH>
          </row>
        </reference14ASU>
        <amount>1</amount>
        <amountRF>1</amountRF>
        <amountNotRF>0</amountNotRF>
        <codeTypeObject>1</codeTypeObject>
        <returnCode>0</returnCode>
        <errorCode>0</errorCode>
        <errorMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
        <title>Справка о дислокации вагонов по списку</title>
      </return>
    </ns2:getReference14ASUResponse>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

**Результат # 2**

```
NOM_VAG: 66236936
NOM_NAK: ЭЫ512933
ROD_VAG_UCH: 60
NAIM_ROD_VAG: Полувагоны
KOD_STR: 643
KOD_SOB: 20
NAIM_KOD_SOB: PЖД
DATE_NACH: 2015-03-07T05:04:00.000
STR_NACH: 643
NAIM_STR_NACH: Российская Федерация
DOR_NACH: 96
NAIM_DOR_NACH: ДAЛЬHEBOCTOЧHAЯ
STAN_NACH: 967808
NAIM_STAN_NACH: ВАНИНО (ЭКСП.)
STR_NAZN: 643
NAIM_STR_NAZN: Российская Федерация
STAN_NAZN: 886808
NAIM_STAN_NAZN: ТЕЯ
DOR_NAZN: 88
NAIM_DOR_NAZN: KPACHOЯPCKAЯ
GRUZPOL: 7035
GRUZPOL_OKPO: 23341100
NAIM_GRUZPOL_OKPO: ООО "ТЕЙСКИЙ РУДНИК"
GRUZOTPR: 2920
GRUZOTPR_OKPO: 0
KOD_GRZ_TGNL: 161043
NAIM_KOD_GRZ: Концентрат угольный
KOD_GRZ_GNG: 992200000000
PROB_GRJ: 75225
PROB_POR: 64651
OS_OTM1: 0
OS_OTM2: 0
OS_OTM3: 0
VES_GRZ: 0
DATE_OP: 2017-08-10T23:00:00.000
DOR_RASCH: 94
NAIM_DOR_RASCH: ЗAБAЙKAЛЬCKAЯ
STAN_OP: 942105
NAIM_STAN_OP: КАДАЛА
KOP_VMD: 80
NAIM_KOP_VMD: Подача вагона на подъездной путь
KOP_PMD: 0
PPV_MEST: 0
PPV_TRANZ: 1
PPV_POR: 1
PPV_GRUJ: 0
PPV_NRP: 1
PPV_RP: 0
VNRP_NEISP: 1
VNRP_SPEC_TEX: 0
DOR_SDACH: 96
NAIM_DOR_SDACH: ДAЛЬHEBOCTOЧHAЯ
INDEX_POEZD: 000000000000000
NOM_POEZD: 0
NPP_VAG: 0
KOL_GRJ_STK: 0
KOL_POR_STK: 0
KOL_GRJ_KTK: 0
KOL_POR_KTK: 0
KOD_GRZ_UCH: 161043
NAIM_KOD_GRZ_UCH: Концентрат угольный
KOL_GRUJ: 0
KOL_POR: 0
KOL_NRP: 0
KOL_VAG: 0
USL_DL_POEZD: 0
VES_BR: 0
PR_STR: 1
NOM_PARK: 3
NAIM_NOM_PARK: Грузовой двор
NOM_PUT: 3
NAIM_NOM_PUT: 3г
KOL_ZPU: 0
KOL_GRJ_KONT: 0
KOL_POR_KONT: 0
DATE_DOSTAV: 2015-03-22T23:59:59.000
RASST_OB: 5545
RASST_STAN_OP: 3017
RASST_STAN_NAZN: 2528
MNAIM_KOP_VMD: ПBПП
PROST_DN: 1270
PROST_MIN: 49
ID_OTPRK: 2096ЭЫ512933
PROST_CH: 11
```